# save to csv with column in Python

Tags: python, csv, cluster-analysis

I need your help to save my clusters from array to a CSV file with column

my expectation in CSV like this

```
text || label
car  || vehicle
cup  || stuff
```

and this my code

```
import csv
row=[["TEXT","LABEL"],
     Corpus['text_final'],Corpus['tags']]
with open('text_label.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be related to clustering.

It looks like you have a list here.  First convert the list to a dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

Then, export the DF to a CSV.  You can use the following template in Python in order to export your pandas DataFrame to a CSV file:

```
df.to_csv(r'C:\\Your_Path_Here\\File_Name.csv', index = False)
```

And if you wish to include the index, then simply remove “, index = False” from the code:

```
df.to_csv(r'C:\\Your_Path_Here\\File_Name.csv')
```